# Rails Validation of Association IDs

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am building a Rails 4.2.4 app where I have Units and Medics.  When I edit each unit I have two spots for the medics, `incharge` and `attendant`.  I want some way to validate that both the `incharge_id` and `attendant_id` are not the same.  That way I can't assign myself as both positions on the unit.

Here is what my model and form view looks like.

**unit.rb**

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attendant, :foreign_key => :attendant_id, :class_name => 'Medic'
  belongs_to :incharge, :foreign_key => :incharge_id, :class_name => 'Medic'
  belongs_to :unit_status
end
```

**medic.rb**

```
class Medic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :units
end
```

**units/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@unit) do |f|  %>
  <%= f.label 'Attendant'%>
  <%= f.collection_select(:attendant_id, Medic.order('name ASC'), :id, :name, {}) %>
  <%= f.label 'In Charge'%>
  <%= f.collection_select(:incharge_id, Medic.order('name ASC'), :id, :name, {}) %>
  <%= f.label 'Unit Status'%>
  <%= f.collection_select(:unit_status_id, UnitStatus.order("status ASC"), :id, :status, {})%>
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

So in summary if I edit a unit and I accidentally assign the `id` of "1" to the unit, I want to error out and give some sort of message, "Cannot assign the same medic to both positions".  Something like that.

The only thing I can think of, is to somehow filter the params in the controller saying if the params of `attendant_id` and `incharge_id` are are == then redirect to the edit_unit_path and display a flash message, "You cannot assign the same medic to both positions".

It seems like it would be better to do validations on the model side instead of stuffing logic in the controller, but I'm not sure how to simultaneous validate the two different columns for uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this on the `Unit` model.

```
  validate :attendant_and_incharge

def attendant_and_incharge
  errors.add(:attendant_id, "can't be the same as the incharge") if attendant_id == incharge_id
end
```

This will not allow me to save the same id to the unit model for attendant_id and incharge_id.  It fails silently and directs to the units_path.  Just need to put some conditional in the controller to redirect to the edit path on failure.  (ThumbsUp)

Comment: In addition to server-side validation it'd be good UX to disallow selected medics to appear in the other medic field, e.g., populate the drop downs dynamically.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the tip, ideally that's my goal with some coffeescript/JS but I was just trying to get the server side validation done first. :)